# Replace value with index number if condition is met in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have this dataframe and I want to replace the value column with a string that contains the index number (+1 and with and F) if the state is "no".

Input:

```
         state value
0         yes     6
1          no    14
2          no    3
3         yes   123
4          no    78
```

Output:

```
         state value
0         yes     6
1          no    F2
2          no    F3
3         yes   123
4          no    F5
```

Comment: Where did the `F` come from? What's the logic for it?

Comment: Im using the dataframe for excel and F is a column I want referenced if the state is "no".

Answer (score 1):

You can check the condition and assign concatenated values using `.loc` :

```py
df.loc[df['state'].eq('no'), 'value'] = 'F' + df['index'].astype(str)
```

**OUTPUT**

```py
   index state value
0      1   yes     6
1      2    no    F2
2      3    no    F3
3      4   yes   123
4      5    no    F5
```

Or, you can create and store the Boolean mask in a separate variable, then implement:

```py
mask=df['state'].eq('no')
df.loc[mask, 'value'] = 'F' + df.loc[mask, 'index'].astype(str)
```

Comment: My bad, I wasnt clear enough. Index isnt a real column, just wanted to use the order of the rows as the value. Is there any way to do this? I edited the original comment.

Comment: @newtocode2 you can replace `df.loc[mask, 'index']` by `df.index[mask]`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `np.where`:

```
df['value'] = np.where(df['state'] == 'no', 'F' + df['index'].astype(str), df['value'])
```